# haw to open new page with click in LIST

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code in html

```
<ion-list>
<div class="card" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
<ion-item>
<div class="video-container">
<img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" 
height="150"/>
<img class="simple" ng-src="{{sign.simple_src}}" width="200" height="150"/>
</div>

 <div class="item item-icon-left assertive">
 <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
  {{sign.text}}
  </div>
  </ion-item>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
```

I am trying to achieve the following

- I need to know which text user has selected to make redirection in other page.
- Each text has its corresponding page.

Comment: ng-click https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: Each text has corresponding page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just need to add ng-click function in you item list, and you can just pass txt prams and redirect it.

```
<ion-list>
<div class="card" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
<ion-item ng-click="onSelect(sign.text)">
<div class="video-container">
<img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" 
height="150"/>
<img class="simple" ng-src="{{sign.simple_src}}" width="200" height="150"/>
</div>
 <div class="item item-icon-left assertive">
 <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
  {{sign.text}}
  </div>
  </ion-item>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
```

in Controller code you need to just create function

```
$scope.onSelect = function (text){
      //if you using ui-state
   $state.go('stateName', {txt: text})
}
```

if you using angularjs routing then

```
$location.path('/stateName/').search({txt: text});
```

URL will look like  `/stateName/?txt=value`

Comment: Please Sumit i have another question
I can when I select an image through checkbox
This image to put in a textarea?

Comment: @NozhaGharnougui your que. is not clear to me could you please elaborate it.  (I am not getting you select image and its put into text area ? )

Comment: Yes want here html code
When I select an image through checkbox I see this image in textarea
<ion-list>
<div class="card" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
<ion-item>
<div class="video-container">
<img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" 
height="150"/>
<img class="simple" ng-src="{{sign.simple_src}}" width="200" height="150"/>
</div>

 <div class="item item-icon-left assertive">
 <i class="icon ion-document"></i>
  {{sign.text}}
  </div>
    <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>

  </ion-item>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
  <textarea></textarea>

Comment: you need to create same function as you created for redirect. and when you click on check box pass sign.animated_src and  probaly its multiple images so you can just push this image source in object and display it in text are or where you want to show it . 
it would be great if you create new que. for same.